# Textlocal: What happens to messages scheduled in future whose template is changed (after scheduling)

Tags: ruby, templates, sms

I have scheduled my message for a future date. The message template used was the following:
"Hi, we have sent you a text" while scheduling the messages.

Now, if I change the template in between today and the scheduled date, to 
"This is the new template", will the message get delivered? Or will it not get sent due to template error?

Also, if the messages are sent, what is the template of messages used in these? The new one or the the one with which they were scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with ruby, per say.

You are using the [txtlocal API](http://api.txtlocal.com/docs/sendsms) to create a scheduled SMS. When that event is scheduled, it on their servers, not yours. So if you then change the template, it cannot possibly propagate 
that change to the scheduled messages automatically.

In order to implement this, you would need to [fetch the scheduled messages](http://api.txtlocal.com/docs/scheduledmessages/getscheduledmessages), [cancel any that need changing](http://api.txtlocal.com/docs/scheduledmessages/cancelscheduledmessages) (unless there's a way to *update* scheduled messages that I cannot see?), then re-schedule them.

Comment: I was not sure if scheduled messages will get delivered or not if the template is changed after they were scheduled. But, I found out that there will be no error. 
Anyways, thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question.

If the messages are scheduled and we change the template afterwards, the messages will be delivered without any error but with old template.